# how to parse files using ebrowse

Tags: emacs

I have a folder tree which contains my C++ files. After reading this document, 
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ebrowse/Generating-browser-files.html#Generating-browser-files
still don't know how to parse all my c++ files in folder tree easily.

I can execute the command below in each folder manually, but looks stupid. I can write some scripts to do it recursively, but want to know any better idea here.

```
ebrowse *.h
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use ebrowse at work. I don't have my bash alias at hand, but from memory it looks like that:

```
ebrowse $(find . -name "*.[hc]pp")
```

Don't hesitate to replace the `.` with the path to the root of your project.

Answer (score 1):

How about open it in `dired` buffer, then <kbd>M-x</kbd>`find-name-dired`<kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>`*.h`<kbd>t</kbd><kbd>!</kbd>`ebrowse *` ?

In other words: use `dired` to locate all files you need, then run shell command on them, shell command being `ebrowse`?

Comment: when execute 'ebrowse % ?' in mini buffer, I got a few lines of 

  %:1: cannot open

Comment: @DeanChen sorry, I meant `*`, not `%` - it means to paste all files marked into command invocation template.

Answer (score 0):

How'bout `ebrowse **/*.h **/*.cpp`?  Don't know which shells support `**` nowadays, but at least Zsh has supported it for a decade or two.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Don't know why the author of ebrowse didn't offer the bais example for showing how to use it. Stupid document is best for newer.